# Rblpapi / bdh - how to download prices for all weekdays - regardless if it is a bank holiday

Tags: bloomberg

Using `bdh()`, I am trying to download historic weekday prices regardless if the weekday is a holiday or not. The default does not return weekday bank holidays. The only option is to return all calendar days.

The override should be Days=W, but I get an error. It would be great if someone could point me into the right direction. Many thanks!

```
blpConnect()

startdate <- as.Date("1999-01-29")


tickers <-  c("SPX Index","VIX Index")

opt <- c("periodicitySelection"="DAILY","currency"="USD")
overrides.week <- "Days"
names(overrides.week) = "W"
```

or

```
overrride.week <- c("Days"="W")

p.d.raw <- bdh(tickers, 
               fields="LAST PRICE",
               start = startdate, 
               end=Sys.Date(), 
               options=opt, 
               override=overrides.week)
```

gives the error **Choice sub-element not found for name 'securityData'.**

Answer (score 2):

This was one solution:

```
option.fields <- c("periodicitySelection", "nonTradingDayFillOption",
                   "nonTradingDayFillMethod", "periodicityAdjustment",
                   "adjustmentFollowDPDF", "currency")

option.values <- c("DAILY", "NON_TRADING_WEEKDAYS", "NIL_VALUE", 
                   "CALENDAR", "TRUE", "USD")

opt <- structure(option.values, names = option.fields)

p.d.raw <- bdh(tickers, 
               fields="LAST PRICE", 
               start=startdate, 
               end=Sys.Date(), 
               options=opt)
```